# How to check for command return codes inside a ruby shell script?

Tags: ruby, shell

I have a simple shell script written in ruby that runs some predefined commands and saves the output strings.

The script works well, but I need a way branch conditionally if the command fails. I've tried using the `$?` object but the script exits before it gets there.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

def run_command(cmd)
  `#{cmd}`
  if $?.success?
    # continue as normal
  else
    # ignore this command and move on
  end
end

run_command('ls')
run_command('not_a_command')

# Output:
# No such file or directory - not_a_command (Errno::ENOENT)...
```

I've tried `$?.exitstatus` or even just puts `$?` but it always exits before it gets there because the script is obviously running the command before hitting that line.

Is there a way to check if the command will run *before actually running it* in the script?

Hope that's clear, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `system` (which returns true or false depending on exit code) instead of backticks (which return output string):

```
if system(cmd)
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

If you want it to run quietly without polluting your logs / output:

```
system(cmd, out: File::NULL, err: File::NULL)
```

Comment: Great solution and extremely useful option to run it quietly too. Thanks for the answer! @BroiSatse